# isDisplayed() method execution time takes too long

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, webdriverwait

I'm working on Java Selenium project and using `isDisplayed()` method to verify that some elements displayed or not displayed on the page, and execution of each method like that takes around 45 sec, is there any suggestions why it could take that long, can it be specified some waits on framework level? 
Note: framework created not by me, I'm just updating it.\

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='productLIGrpTermDeal_chkPartySlf']//following-sibling::div")    
List<WebElement> GroupTermDealerLifeInsuranceSelf1;


public boolean verify_Icon_Is_Not_Displayed_() throws Exception {

    try {
        log.debug("Validate Icon is not Displayed");

        Assert.assertEquals(0, GroupTermDealerLifeInsuranceSelf1.size());

        System.out.println("Icon is not Displayed");
        log.info("Icon is validated successfully || Pass");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Icon is Displayed");
        log.error("Not able to Validate Icon is Displayed || Fail" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code in your original post.

Comment: added code to question

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` for implicit wait (Every Wait for finding element) in addition for a specific element wait you can use  `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(>someid>)));`

Comment: I didn't have `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` specified. Now I put this and specified 5 sec but no changes, it still waits around 45 sec

Comment: implicit wait isn't going to make it any faster

Comment: any suggestions what can make that much slow, because I'm executing same scenario but using Protractor and those steps take like 1-2 sec

Answer (score 0):

You can amend your XPath query to limit the size of the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to 1 (or whatever is the maximum value you're using in your tests). It can be achieved by adding [position() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) to the end of your locator like:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='productLIGrpTermDeal_chkPartySlf']//following-sibling::div/*[position()<=1]")
```

Once you apply this change the time to locate the [WebElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) will be reduced proportionally to the number of matches in the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)